# ssh raspberrypi.local not resolving in OSX

Tags: ssh, raspbian-jessie, macos, raspbian-buster

Until recently

```
ssh pi@raspberypi.local
```

worked as would one expect it to normally. However within the last few days it no longer returns anything and will just sit forever until killed manually. The pi in question is ping-able and can be accessed via the IP returned by pinging it. Furthermore, changing the hostname of the pi to anything else causes

```
ssh pi@newname.local
```

to work just fine. The scope of the issue appears to be limited just to the raspberrypi.local hostname. I've examined my /etc/hosts file as well as removed anything related in known_hosts (via `ssh-keygen -R raspberrypi.local`), but the issue persists. Can anyone advise?

Comment: What operating system do you use? Jessie or Buster? Does the Raspberry Pi is the only one in your network?

Comment: Issue persists across both. I'm 99% sure this is central to my Macbook and not the Pi(s). I have multiple Pis on my network but each with their own hostnames; all work as expected. The issue is also not network specific as I've tested against on others and the issue remains.

Comment: If this is not a problem of the Raspberry Pi then you ask on the wrong site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the issue was central to fish for some reason. Moving to bash caused ssh to work as expected. Returning to fish and typing out `ssh pi@raspberrypi.local` in full caused everything to work correctly; no idea why. Best guess is that something was wonky in the stored smart command stuff fish does.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I do not have a simple solution.

Generally I find [Zero-conf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking)
 resolution works reliably, but I have encountered problems.

Indeed, at the moment, my Pi4 is not being resolved at MilliwaysPi4.local although I have an open `ssh` session to the Pi4.

Discovery works by sending a broadcast message (can't remember the address off the top of my head), but this can by foiled, I suspect by `arp` caching.

The "fix" is to reboot routers (and the Mac), but this is rather drastic.
Pinging the Mac from the Pi is often sufficient to wake it up.

This is NOT a problem with the Pi, but is somewhere in your network.

Comment: Good answer, but it appears that the problem was both local and even more so limited in scope to fish. See my answer below.