# "Could not resolve hostname" on Pi for local services

Tags: ssh, dhcp, dns

My Pi cannot resolve hostnames of other services in the same local network. Resolution of external services works fine.

```
$ nslookup example.com
Server:     127.0.0.1
Address:    127.0.0.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   example.com
Address: 93.184.216.34
Name:   example.com
Address: 2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946
```

For example there's a host `thesource.local` that I connect to from my e.g. MacBook but name resolution from the Pi fails:

```
$ avahi-browse -a|grep SSH
+   eth0 IPv6 thesource                                     SSH Remote Terminal  local
+   eth0 IPv4 thesource                                     SSH Remote Terminal  local
$ ssh my-user@thesource.local
ssh: Could not resolve hostname thesource.local: Name or service not known
```

This is strictly an issue with *local* names *on the Pi*. Connecting from other hosts (e.g. the MacBook) *to* the Pi using `ssh my-user@mypi.local` works just fine (thanks to Bonjour/Avahi I guess).

My `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` looks like so as I need a static IP address:

```
interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.0.10/24
static ip6_address=fd51:42f8:caae:d92e::ff/64
static routers=192.168.0.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.1 9.9.9.9 2620:fe::fe
```

For the sake of completeness here's the (abbreviated) `ipconfig` output:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.10  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::8aa2:f238:cae7:82f3  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether dc:a6:32:0f:cd:a4  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
```

**Update 2020-03-29**

More information asked for in the comments:

```
$ grep -v "#" /etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf|grep -v "\["

use-ipv4=yes
use-ipv6=yes
ratelimit-interval-usec=1000000
ratelimit-burst=1000

enable-wide-area=yes

publish-hinfo=no
publish-workstation=no

$ service avahi-daemon status
● avahi-daemon.service - Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/avahi-daemon.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2020-03-28 19:46:11 CET; 17h ago
 Main PID: 329 (avahi-daemon)
   Status: "avahi-daemon 0.7 starting up."
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 4616)
   Memory: 1.2M
   CGroup: /system.slice/avahi-daemon.service
           ├─329 avahi-daemon: running [white-rose.local]
           └─340 avahi-daemon: chroot helper
```

Comment: Can you ping the IP address of thesource.local from the Pi and the Mac?

Comment: Yes, connectivity is ok but name resolution not. I can ping and telnet into `thesource.local`.

Comment: On the Mac, can you ssh my-user@thesource.local fine?

Comment: Have you tried this sans `.local`? `avahi-browse` obviously finds `thesource`... If so this may be a matter of that getting *appended* on the Mac.

Comment: Yes, I had already tried w/o `.local`. The local "domain" is also listed in the last column of the Avahi browser output. However, you make me think that it would probably be more reasonable to expect `thesource` to work rather than `thesource.local`. That latter is the mDNS/Bonjour/ZeroConf name that SSH/ICMP/etc. on the Pi probably are not aware of?

Comment: Did you try the ssh from the Mac?

Comment: What's the DNS list on the Mac? And, are you sure the list on RPi and Mac are the same? -- If you have access to external hostnames, maybe the `192.168.0.1` does not work and all the DNS queries forwarded to the secondary DNS server which is working on the global/external network. **I suggest** you remove `9.9.9.9` and `2620:fe::fe` form the `dhcpcd.conf`. As you know, after that, reboot the RPi or the related service.

Comment: From all Macs I can ssh into every other Mac and into every Pi by using `<host>.local`. However, as I said this is probably more thanks to mDNS/Bonjour than thanks to DNS. Removing the extra DNS servers from `dhcpcd.conf` and leaving only `192.168.0.1` has zero effect (server list is then identical to what I have on the Mac). `$ nslookup thesource
Server:  127.0.0.1
Address: 127.0.0.1#53

** server can't find thesource: NXDOMAIN`

Comment: What is the contents of  /etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf on the Pi that cannot reach the other? Can you also run service avahi-daemon status and post the output here?

Comment: See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/100378/8697

Comment: @Andyroo I added the info you asked for. @milliways thanks for being so aktive here. I had read you fantastic answers to some of the related questions before I posted. If I get that Q you link to correctly then they're dealing with the exact opposite problem: `<mypi>.local` is not reachable from the rest of the network - in my case it's the other way around (other hosts not reachable by name _from_ the Pi).

Comment: Did the last command give anything from the log? I would have expected lines like Mar 23 13:12:05 lan-services avahi-daemon[247]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.10. for connections...

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue when I did a clean buster install on a new sd card.  It took a bit of digging, but found the readme.md in the nss-mDns GitHub repository wants to include mdns4 on the hosts line of /etc/nsswitch.conf:

`hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4`

Since other hosts on the network could resolve the new Pi, <f>.local, I assumed it's mDns was properly broadcasting.  In my case, running `avahi-resolve -n <g>.local` on <f> would find the address, but `ping <g>.local` would not; so it pointed me to how names were resolving.

It was hard to find because my working pi, <b>.local and the old image on the sd card I swapped out <g>.local didn't have that in nsswitch.conf.  But, <b> is running Jessie; and I think <g> is running Stretch(?).

Comment: You did not installed a clean buster image, or you modified it. The line in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` is given by default on an unmodified Raspberry Pi OS image. It is set with installed `libnss-mdns`.